# Binomial theorem for prime exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Could you explain to me why for prime $p$ we have the following?

$$(x+y)^p - (x^p + y^p)= x^p +  \binom{p}{1}x^{p-1}y +  \binom{p}{2}x^{p-2}y^2 +  \binom{p}{p-1}xy^{p-1} + y^p.$$

I found it here: [Abstract Algebra - Solutions to Homework (pdf)](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~robertop/Courses/Math_454/Handouts/HW_Sep_16_sols.pdf),
solution 5d, page 3.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but this looks to me like a mistake (or a lazy omission), and $(x+y)^p - (x^p + y^p)= x^p +  \binom{p}{1}x^{p-1}y +  \binom{p}{2}x^{p-2}y^2 +  \binom{p}{p-1}xy^{p-1} + y^p$ should be $(x+y)^p - (x^p + y^p)= x^p +  \binom{p}{1}x^{p-1}y + \binom{p}{2}x^{p-2}y^2 + \cdots + \binom{p}{p-1}xy^{p-1} + y^p - (x^{p} + y^{p})$

Comment: I also thought so, but I wanted to make sure :) Thank you. So now, after subtracting $x^p$ and $y^p$ we get that all components are divisible by $p$ so we have that  $(x+y)^p - (x^p + y^p) \equiv 0$ mod $p$, is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly right; each of the binomial coefficients is divisible by $p$ (except for $\begin{pmatrix} p\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} p\\p\end{pmatrix}$), so the so-called "freshman's dream" holds mod $p$: $(x + y)^p \equiv x^p + y^p\pmod p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, what's in the notes is incorrect. We should have
\begin{align*}
(x + y)^p - (x^p + y^p) &= x^p + \begin{pmatrix} p\\ 1\end{pmatrix}x^{p - 1}y + \begin{pmatrix} p\\ 2\end{pmatrix} x^{p - 2}y^2 + \ldots + \begin{pmatrix} p\\ p - 1\end{pmatrix}x y^{p - 1} + y^p - (x^p + y^p)\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} p\\ 1\end{pmatrix}x^{p - 1}y + \begin{pmatrix} p\\ 2\end{pmatrix} x^{p - 2}y^2 + \ldots + \begin{pmatrix} p\\ p - 1\end{pmatrix}x y^{p - 1}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{p-1}\begin{pmatrix}p\\k\end{pmatrix}x^{p - k} y^k.
\end{align*}
I can only assume the writer of the notes got hungry and left in the middle of writing the solutions, and forgot to write a few terms ($\ldots$) upon returning.

Comment: "Hey John, we're going for lunch, are you coming?" - "Yea sure, one second, I'll just finish this quickly."

Comment: Nice :) Thank you a lot.